# mongorestore hanging when restoring to a replica-set

Tags: mongodb

With the following .mongorc.js:

```
rs.slaveOk();

function startRS() {
    config = {_id: 'rs', members: [{_id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017', priority: 1}, {_id: 1, host: 'localhost:27016', priority: 0}]};
    rs.initiate(config);
}
```

And the following startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /data/db/rs{0,1} >/dev/null 2>&1

/opt/mongo-db/bin/mongod --replSet rs --port 27016 --dbpath /data/db/rs1 &

/opt/mongo-db/bin/mongod --replSet rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db/rs0 &

/opt/mongo-db/bin/mongo --eval "startRS()"
```

Mongo starts up all fine. But when I try to run mongorestore as

```
$ /opt/mongo-db/bin/mongorestore  --drop dump/
```

it hangs while continuously writing

```
2018-06-29T19:35:47.661+0200    [########################]    ardoq-common.model.versions   753KB/753KB  (100.0%)
2018-06-29T19:35:47.661+0200    [#####...................]  iansneworg.component.versions  456KB/1.99MB   (22.4%)
2018-06-29T19:35:47.661+0200    [........................]        home.component.versions  447KB/12.9MB    (3.4%)
2018-06-29T19:35:47.661+0200    [#.......................]   piedpiper.component.versions  593KB/12.4MB    (4.7%)
2018-06-29T19:35:47.661+0200
2018-06-29T19:35:50.662+0200    [########################]    ardoq-common.model.versions   753KB/753KB  (100.0%)
2018-06-29T19:35:50.662+0200    [#####...................]  iansneworg.component.versions  456KB/1.99MB   (22.4%)
2018-06-29T19:35:50.662+0200    [........................]        home.component.versions  447KB/12.9MB    (3.4%)
2018-06-29T19:35:50.662+0200    [#.......................]   piedpiper.component.versions  593KB/12.4MB    (4.7%)
2018-06-29T19:35:50.662+0200
2018-06-29T19:35:53.664+0200    [########################]    ardoq-common.model.versions   753KB/753KB  (100.0%)
2018-06-29T19:35:53.664+0200    [#####...................]  iansneworg.component.versions  456KB/1.99MB   (22.4%)
2018-06-29T19:35:53.664+0200    [........................]        home.component.versions  447KB/12.9MB    (3.4%)
2018-06-29T19:35:53.664+0200    [#.......................]   piedpiper.component.versions  593KB/12.4MB    (4.7%)
2018-06-29T19:35:53.664+0200
```

While mongodb logs

```
2018-06-29T19:37:57.368+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62632 #60 (11 connections now open)
2018-06-29T19:37:57.372+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62634 #10 (4 connections now open)
2018-06-29T19:37:57.377+0200 I COMMAND  [conn60] CMD: drop home.component.versions
2018-06-29T19:37:57.377+0200 I STORAGE  [conn60] dropCollection: home.component.versions (623af0a3-ee8d-4b8a-9e28-349bd1094b32) - renaming to drop-pending collection: home.system.drop.1530293877i1t5.component.versions with drop optime { ts: Timestamp(1530293877, 1), t: 5 }
2018-06-29T19:37:57.379+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62636 #61 (12 connections now open)
2018-06-29T19:37:57.379+0200 I STORAGE  [conn60] createCollection: home.component.versions with generated UUID: f5cb88f9-df22-4990-9ef8-cdd689892b50
2018-06-29T19:37:57.380+0200 I COMMAND  [repl writer worker 9] CMD: drop home.component.versions
2018-06-29T19:37:57.380+0200 I STORAGE  [repl writer worker 9] dropCollection: home.component.versions (623af0a3-ee8d-4b8a-9e28-349bd1094b32) - renaming to drop-pending collection: home.system.drop.1530293877i1t5.component.versions with drop optime { ts: Timestamp(1530293877, 1), t: 5 }
2018-06-29T19:37:57.382+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62638 #62 (13 connections now open)
2018-06-29T19:37:57.383+0200 I COMMAND  [conn61] CMD: drop piedpiper.component.versions
2018-06-29T19:37:57.383+0200 I STORAGE  [conn61] dropCollection: piedpiper.component.versions (1eaf6561-eea5-414d-80d2-b914f5110559) - renaming to drop-pending collection: piedpiper.system.drop.1530293877i3t5.component.versions with drop optime { ts: Timestamp(1530293877, 3), t: 5 }
2018-06-29T19:37:57.384+0200 I STORAGE  [repl writer worker 0] createCollection: home.component.versions with provided UUID: f5cb88f9-df22-4990-9ef8-cdd689892b50
```

This is on MacOS High Sierra with mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-3.6.5

I have this exact (well probably not exact since it's working) setup running on another Mac also with MacOS High Sierra, but probably with mongodb-3.6.4.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mongorestore command line is connecting to a standalone mongod on localhost on the default port, the log snippet you posted indicates a secondary node that will not be able to take writes.

In order for monorestore to automatically switch to the writeable node, you will need to specify the replica set in the comand line

```
connection options:
-h, --host=<hostname>                                     mongodb host to connect to (setname/host1,host2 for replica sets)
--port=<port>                                         server port (can also use --host hostname:port)
```

like

```
/opt/mongo-db/bin/mongorestore --host=rs/localhost:27017,localhost:27016 --drop dump/
```